# How to check version of ansible-modules-core?

Tags: ansible

Is that means ansible modules are in same version with `ansible`

> [Ansible modules - these modules ship with ansible](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core)

If not then how to check which version of ansible modules I have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Q:** Are ansible modules the same version with `ansible`?

**A:** Looking at the `ansible` repository -> tag `stable-v2.0`.
https://github.com/ansible/ansible/tree/stable-2.0/lib/ansible/modules

Since `ansible/modules/core` is a submodule-reference to the `ansible-modules` repository found [here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/tree/stable-2.0/lib/ansible/modules). This means that when an ansible developer do a `git clone --recursive` to checkout the entire set of code, `git` will checkout codes from `ansible` and `ansible-modules` repositories to make up the "entire set of code".

So when a developer goes on to build the binary from the full `ansible` source code, I would assume that only one distinct version number is given to it.

Therefore, short answer is; **yes**. They share the same version number.

Answer (score 1):

There's 99% probability that you have it the same version as Ansible "kernel", unless you installed Ansible from sources and updated modules subtrees manually.

`ansible-modules-core` and `ansible-modules-extras` were split from main `ansible` repo for some time, but later merged again. You can read about it [here](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/repomerge.html).

But Ansible packages has been always released as self-contained, so if your modules' versions are the same as Ansible version in `ansible --version` command.